# Running a single python script across multiple AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to run a python script that will access different AWS Account(stg,qa,dev). How can I achieve this without violating any security best practices?

Comment: Do you mean AWS Lambda by python script? Could you please describe your current setup and he security concerns that you have? In general you can find most common security recommendations in the official AWS whitepaper https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS_Security_Best_Practices.pdf

Comment: This is close (uses AWS CLI instead of Python): [Running AWS CLI Commands Across All Accounts In An AWS Organization - Alestic.com](https://alestic.com/2019/12/aws-cli-across-organization-accounts/?ck_subscriber_id=512837985)

Comment: It may or may not be lambda, ultimate goal is to access AWS resources of different account from one single account. Current setup is like I have one management account which have access to other accounts(Prd,dev,stg etc). And I am not supposed to run this script as a dedicated AWS IAM user. The application would be a web application(for UI may be in nodejs) and from frontend the python script will be triggered  which will access resources across various accounts and generate a report to save it into a S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with John with using iam roles to manage the access. You can extend this further by only using roles instead of users if you run your script from lambda.

To elaborate further, you will need to have two types of iam roles: target roles and a source role.

## Target Role

The target roles will live in each account. This role will need to have permissions to be assumed by the source role.

## Source Role

The source role will live in an account that you want to have access to all other accounts. This role will need to have the permission to assume other roles. The corresponding iam action is `sts:AssumeRole`.

## Code

Below I have provided the code I have used in the past. Normally I would place this code in a lambda that is in an account that can control other accounts, such as a SharedServices or a DevOps account. You may want to refer to the [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) for the role assumption.

```
import boto3

def role_arn_to_session(**args):
    client = boto3.client('sts')
    response = client.assume_role(**args)
    return boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

# This decides what role to use, a name of the session you will start, and potentially an external id.
# The external id can be used as a passcode to protect your role.
def set_boto3_clients(accountId):
    return role_arn_to_session(
        RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::' + accountId + ':role/TargetRole',
        RoleSessionName='AssumeTargetRole',
        ExternalId=os.environ['ExternalId']
    )

def handler(event, context):

    for accountId in accountList:

        boto3InDifferentAccount = setup_client(accountId)

        # You can then use this boto3InDifferentAccount as if you are using boto in another account
        # For example: s3 = boto3InDifferentAccount.client('s3')
        runScriptInAccount(boto3InDifferentAccount)
```

Note: when using this kind of role assumption you will need to configure how long you may want to assume the role. The default is 3600 secs, but you can edit this by changing the target role confiruagtion and the assumerole call parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ben for your response. This idea came to my mind at first but for security, I am not supposed to create these extra roles in each accounts. Any other alternatives?

Comment: Ultimately, if you are accessing aws resources from different accounts you will need to either iam roles or users to access them. From your comment to the question, I would still aim to use a similar solution as above because [aws recommends](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-iam/). In order to do this securely from your front end application, you may want to place the calling script in a lambda and use api gateway as a trigger. You can add an additional lambda to protect your api gateway in the form of a lambda authorizer.

Comment: If you truly cannot create additional roles, you potentially can create a lambda with an api gateway trigger in in each account and call each one from your central account in the form of a rest api call. However, you would need to make sure your api's are secure.

Comment: Thanks you very much @Ben . I'd like to go with the approach that you told like using api gateway and lambda. But for lambda to access different accounts from one central account I need to use CloudCustodian as per the organisation requirement. Doing some research on that and please let me know if you have any input on that like running a single python script to access multiple account using Cloud Custodian.

Answer (score 1):

A 'clean' way to do this would be:

- Create an **IAM User** in one account that will be used by the Python app
- Create an **IAM Role** in each target account (with the same name), with permissions such that the role can be *assumed* by the IAM User
- Load the list of the accounts into your app. Have it loop through each account, assume the role and access the account.