# How to run a python script file in AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to run a python script file while in the AWS CLI.  Does anyone have the syntax for that please?  I've tried a few variations but without success:

`aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters commands=["/Documents/aws_instances_summary.py"]`

I'm not looking to connect to a particular EC2 instance as the script gathers information about all instances

Comment: If you want to retrieve info about EC2 instances have you considered Ansible? Specifically, the `aws.ec2_instance_info` plugin may be what you need. Details here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_instance_info_module.html#ansible-collections-amazon-aws-ec2-instance-info-module

Comment: I've been specifically asked to run this particular .py script, so I need to figure out how to do that.  I appreciate the suggestion though

Comment: `aws ssm send-command` is used to run commands on one or more managed nodes (EC2 instances). If you want to run a python script but not on a particular instance, you can run locally `python /Documents/aws_instances_summary.py`

Comment: @OmarRosadio I need to run this against several large AWS accounts, I was sure there must be a way to do it after logging on the the AWS CLI for each account

Comment: You would need to create the script to iterate over accounts (using IAM User credentials, IAM named-profiles or assuming a role in each account). I think your case is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623812/running-a-single-python-script-across-multiple-aws-account

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking to run 1 script that runs against multiple AWS accounts at once, I'm happy to run it manually for each account by applying the secret key etc in AWS CLI for each account, then running the script.  I 'm just looking for the command to run the py script to query EC2 without specifying an instance.  Hopefully it's possible

Comment: You don't have to run a script in EC2 for it to be able to query the EC2 API. You can run it anywhere you have the awscli (or an SDK) and a set of appropriately-permissioned AWS credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aws ssm send-command` runs the command **on** an EC2 instance, not on your local computer.

From your comments, it looks like you are actually trying to determine how to configure the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3) with AWS API credentials, so you can run the script from your local computer and get information about the AWS account.

You would not use the AWS CLI tool at all for this purpose. Instead you would simply run the Python script directly, having configured the appropriate environment variables, or `~/.aws/credentials` file, on your local computer with the API credentials. Please see [the official documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html) for configuring AWS API credentials for Boto3.

A minimal example would look something like this:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
python aws_instances_summary.py
```